# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, xelement to listview

Tags: c#

```
    private void ButtonRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument request = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument fil = new XmlDocument();
        request = xmlRequest1();
        fil = xmlFilter();
        response = doAvail(request, fil);
        XElement po = XElement.Parse(response.OuterXml);
        IEnumerable<XElement> childElements = from el in po.Elements() select el;
        foreach (XElement el in childElements)
        { 



            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
                    {
                        el.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                        el.Descendants("PCC").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                        el.Descendants("BusinessTitle").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                    });
            ListViewResult.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

ı have an error when i loop to the liesviewitem.
please assist,thanks.

Comment: which line is giving error?

Comment: after i loop for foreach then pass to the line  ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
                    {
                        el.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                        el.Descendants("PCC").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                        el.Descendants("BusinessTitle").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                    });
            ListViewResult.Items.Add(item); then error promt for object reference not set to an obejct.

Comment: it means that either of el.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault().Value, el.Descendants("PCC").FirstOrDefault().Value or this el.Descendants("BusinessTitle").FirstOrDefault().Value is returning null. Debug it and check what is null.

Comment: oh okie so i need to have some vaidation to catch if theres a null value? how to do that?

Comment: That's really not a great way of converting an XmlDocument to XDocument...

Comment: can you please teach me how to handle this error,please im like stuck here for a week already sir.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `FirstOrDefault()`, which will return `null` if it doesn't find any values - but you're then *unconditionally* dereferencing that return value. If you *do* want to handle the case where you don't get any values, just use a cast to `string` instead of the `Value` property:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
{
    (string) el.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault(),
    (string) el.Descendants("PCC").FirstOrDefault(),
    (string) el.Descendants("BusinessTitle").FirstOrDefault(),
});
```

Now the array will contain a null reference for any missing element. I don't know whether the list view will handle that or not, mind you.

If you *don't* want to handle the case where the name/pcc/title aren't found, then use `First` to make that clear:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
{
    el.Descendants("Name").First().Value,
    el.Descendants("PCC").First().Value,
    el.Descendants("BusinessTitle").First().Value,
});
```

That will currently still give you an exception, of course - just a clearer one. My *guess* is that you're missing a namespace - that you actually want:

```
XNamespace ns = "some namespace URL here";
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
{
    el.Descendants(ns + "Name").First().Value,
    el.Descendants(ns + "PCC").First().Value,
    el.Descendants(ns + "BusinessTitle").First().Value,
});
```

... but we can't tell what namespace you need without knowing what your XML looks like.

Comment: public XmlDocument xmlRequest1()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string req = "<AgencyInfoDisplay_7>>\r\n";
            req += " <AgncyInfoMods>\r\n";
            req += "  <PCCAry>\r\n";
            req += "   <PCC>3DM7</PCC>\r\n";
            req += "   <PCC>54AN</PCC>\r\n";
            req += "  </PCCAry>\r\n";
            req += " </AgncyInfoMods>>\r\n";
            req += "</AgencyInfoDisplay_7>\r\n";
            doc.LoadXml(req);
            return doc;
        }

Comment: @SiriKit: Oh my goodness - *please* don't build XML like that. And where do you expect that to get a `Name` or `BusinessTitle` element from? Do you even need `XmlDocument` at all? Why not just build an `XDocument` to start with?

Comment: i cant add sir the xml response,it says it too long.

Comment: i will email it to you sir the xml file. @Jon Skeet